# Remove dupilcate items from Subarray PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am wondering if anyone can advise on how to remove duplicate items from just the subarray.
From the example below index 0 has blue and red, and index 2 has blue yellow blue. I want the duplicates to be removed at the index level so the output of index 0 should remain blue red and the output of index 2 should be blue yellow.

I have used a few methods but all the attempts I have made do not remove at the sub-array level.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => blue
        [1] => red
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => green
        [1] => brown
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => blue
        [1] => yellow
        [2] => blue
    )

)

Should return as:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => blue
        [1] => red
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => green
        [1] => brown
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => blue
        [1] => yellow

    )

)
```

Thank You

Comment: Please include a [mre]. You should show some code, show us what you've tried.

Comment: tip: [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)` for this:

```
$array = [
    ['blue', 'red'],
    ['green', 'brown'],
    ['blue', 'yellow', 'blue']
    ];

$new_array = [];


foreach ( $array as $single ) {
    $new_array[] = array_unique( $single );
}
```

`$new_array` will `print_r` to this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => brown
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => blue
            [1] => yellow
        )

)
```

Comment: Great stuff thank you. I knew it would be simple was having a mental block for some reason